# Typescript is not giving error for proptype, function types etc in Next.js project

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, next.js

Hello all i am making a project with typescript i have added rules and many things but not getting the types error for function, props etc. basiclly **if we use any function then have to pass :JSX.Element/ :React.fn / :void eg.**

> const ImageComponent = (): JSX.Element => ()

if we dont use this type then TS thow errors but i am not getting please help me to fix the issue

*package.json*

```
{
  "name": "antd-redux-ts-sass",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "dev": "next dev",
    "build": "next build",
    "start": "next start",
    "lint": "next lint"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@ant-design/icons": "^4.8.0",
    "@next/eslint-plugin-next": "^13.0.6",
    "antd": "^5.0.6",
    "import": "^0.0.6",
    "next": "13.0.6",
    "react": "18.2.0",
    "react-dom": "18.2.0",
    "sass": "^1.56.2"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@types/node": "18.11.13",
    "@types/react": "18.0.1",
    "@types/react-dom": "18.0.9",
    "@typescript-eslint/eslint-plugin": "5.0.0",
    "@typescript-eslint/parser": "^5.46.1",
    "eslint": "8.0.1",
    "eslint-config-next": "13.0.6",
    "eslint-config-standard-with-typescript": "^23.0.0",
    "eslint-import-resolver-typescript": "^3.5.2",
    "eslint-plugin-import": "2.25.2",
    "eslint-plugin-n": "15.0.0",
    "eslint-plugin-promise": "6.0.0",
    "eslint-plugin-react": "^7.31.11",
    "eslint-plugin-simple-import-sort": "^8.0.0",
    "typescript": "*"
  }
}
```

*.eslintrc*

```
module.exports = {
  env: {
    browser: true,
    es2021: true
  },
//   parser: '@typescript-eslint/parser',
  parserOptions: {
    ecmaVersion: 8,
    ecmaFeatures: {
      experimentalObjectRestSpread: true,
      jsx: true
    },
    sourceType: 'module'
  },
  plugins: [
    'react',
    '@typescript-eslint',
    'import',
    '@next/next',
    '@next/eslint-plugin-next',
    'simple-import-sort',
    'better-styled-components',
    'jest'
  ],
  extends: [
    'next/core-web-vitals',
    'eslint:recommended',
    'plugin:@typescript-eslint/recommended',
    'plugin:react/recommended',
    'standard-with-typescript',
    'next',
    'next/core-web-vitals',
    'eslint:recommended',
    'plugin:@typescript-eslint/recommended',
    'plugin:@typescript-eslint/recommended-requiring-type-checking',
    'plugin:jsx-a11y/recommended',
    'plugin:@next/next/recommended',
    'plugin:import/recommended',
    'plugin:react-hooks/recommended'
  ],
  rules: {
    '@typescript-eslint/no-unused-vars': 'error',
    '@typescript-eslint/no-explicit-any': 'error',
    'import/no-duplicates': 2,
    'import/no-unresolved': 2,
    'import/named': 2,
    semi: [2, 'never'],
    'quote-props': [2, 'as-needed'],
    'object-shorthand': [2, 'always'],
    'no-new-object': 2,
    'no-eval': 2,
    'template-curly-spacing': [2, 'never'],
    'prefer-template': 2,
    quotes: [2, 'single'],
    'react/jsx-filename-extension': [
      1,
      {
        extensions: ['.ts', '.tsx']
      }
    ],
    'default-param-last': 2,
    'space-before-function-paren': [
      2,
      {
        anonymous: 'always',
        named: 'always',
        asyncArrow: 'always'
      }
    ],
    indent: [
      1,
      2,
      {
        SwitchCase: 1,
        ignoredNodes: [
          'TSXElement',
          'TSXElement > *',
          'TSXAttribute',
          'TSXIdentifier',
          'TSXNamespacedName',
          'TSXMemberExpression',
          'TSXSpreadAttribute',
          'TSXExpressionContainer',
          'TSXOpeningElement',
          'TSXClosingElement',
          'TSXText',
          'TSXEmptyExpression',
          'TSXSpreadChild'
        ]
      }
    ],
    'no-inline-comments': 2,
    'no-var': 2,
    'react/react-in-jsx-scope': 0,
    'react/no-danger': 0,
    'react/jsx-indent': [1, 2],
    'react/no-this-in-sfc': 2,
    'react/no-typos': 2,
    'react/no-unused-state': 2,
    'react/jsx-no-bind': [
      2,
      {
        allowArrowFunctions: true,
        allowFunctions: true
      }
    ],
    'no-useless-call': 2,
    'no-useless-computed-key': 2,
    'no-useless-concat': 2,
    'no-useless-constructor': 2,
    'no-useless-rename': 2,
    'no-useless-return': 2,
    camelcase: [
      0,
      {
        properties: 'always',
        ignoreImports: false,
        ignoreGlobals: true,
        allow: ['org_code', 'cookies_jwtToken', 'auth_token']
      }
    ],
    'no-constant-condition': [
      2,
      {
        checkLoops: false
      }
    ],
    'no-console': [
      2,
      {
        allow: ['warn', 'error']
      }
    ],
    'eol-last': ['error', 'always'],
    'no-underscore-dangle': 0,
    'import/no-named-as-default': 0,
    'tsx-a11y/anchor-is-valid': 0,
    'react-hooks/exhaustive-deps': 0,
    '@next/next/no-img-element': 2,
    '@next/next/no-sync-scripts': 1,
    '@next/next/no-css-tags': 2,
    '@next/next/no-document-import-in-page': 2,
    '@next/next/no-html-link-for-pages': 2,
    'consistent-return': 0,
    'simple-import-sort/imports': 'error',
    'simple-import-sort/exports': 'error',
    'no-multi-spaces': 'error',
    'key-spacing': [2, { beforeColon: false, afterColon: true }],
    'keyword-spacing': [2, { before: true, after: true }],
    'new-cap': [2, { newIsCap: true, capIsNew: false }],
    'new-parens': 2,
    'no-array-constructor': 2
  }
}
```

Github repo link: https://github.com/kamalesh777/next-advance

*You can see that many things i have added unnecessary its just because of its not working so tried too much thing to fixed*

Comment: I can only reproduce that if I don't run `yarn install`. After running `yarn install` I can see all the types correctly. What is you IDE?

Comment: no in my case not working for function type checking and i am using VS code editor

Answer (score 0):

You're essentially overriding `eslint-config-next` with your custom .eslint implementation. Many of the other eslint plugins you're calling are already used under the hood. Less is more in this case

You don't need to roll your own eslint any longer, eslint-config-next takes care of it for you. Try replacing it with something like this and let us know how it goes

- `.eslintrc.json`

```json
{
  "root": true,
  "extends": "next/core-web-vitals"
}
```

You should uninstall the following dev dependencies, they're not needed with `eslint-config-next`

```json
{
    "@typescript-eslint/eslint-plugin": "5.0.0",
    "@typescript-eslint/parser": "^5.46.1",
    "eslint-config-standard-with-typescript": "^23.0.0",
    "eslint-import-resolver-typescript": "^3.5.2",
    "eslint-plugin-import": "2.25.2",
    "eslint-plugin-n": "15.0.0",
    "eslint-plugin-promise": "6.0.0",
    "eslint-plugin-react": "^7.31.11"
}
```

Also definitely uninstall the `import` dependency -- that hasn't been updated in the last 9 years. Importing itself is incredibly flexible in next13 out of the box

Remove these two dependencies

```json
{
    "@next/eslint-plugin-next": "^13.0.6",
    "import": "^0.0.6"
}
```

Your repo is also missing a root `next-env.d.ts` file that is usually auto-generated when nextjs detects that you're using typescript which explains why you're not having a good experience

- `next-env.d.ts`

```
/// <reference types="next" />
/// <reference types="next/types/global" />
/// <reference types="next/image-types/global" />

// NOTE: This file should not be edited
// see https://nextjs.org/docs/basic-features/typescript for more information.
```

Make sure to add `next.env.d.ts` to the includes array in `tsconfig.json` for typescript to pick up the declaration file triple slash references

---

Be sure to have your eslint package up to date as well -- I noticed that it is at 8.0.1 but the latest is 8.29.0. Same goes for `@types/react` -- its latest version is `18.26`, which will make it play nicely with `@types/react-dom@^18.0.9` which you do have installed (the latest version of react-dom types)